# MVC: CSS no carga estilos

Tags: php, html, css, mvc, backend

soy nuevo con la comunidad. Quería consultar que tengo mi proyecto de tipo MVC.
Tengo mis directorios así, cada uno tiene los archivos necesarios en php para lograr funcionar la app:

```
/
|_ models/
|_ views/
|_ controllers/
|_ index.php
```

Casi todo esta listo, solo tengo un problema, el archivo **index.php** no carga los estilos cuando hago un require_once() a views/index.php (contiene la vista del proyecto)

*En el views/index.php tengo esto:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Sans:wght@200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <title>CRUD: Inicio</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <p class="parraph">Hola mundo!</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

*Y en el /index.php (raíz) esto:*

```
<?php
    require_once("App/views/index.php");
?>
```

***¿Qué puedo hacer para que los estilos carguen sin hacer el /index.php engorroso ni espaguetti?***

Comment: Bienvenido Leandro, si creaste otra cuenta te sugiero revisar https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1725/c%c3%b3mo-deben-gestionarse-las-cuentas-t%c3%adtere-en-stack-exchange , saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

debes tener en cuenta que la vista de tu proyecto (index) se está mostrando desde tu index raiz así que para cargar el css debes darle el href desde ahí

es decir si tu carpeta css esta dentro de views sería así

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="App/views/css/styles.css">
```

Comment: Sí, justamente utilicé algo parecido en el index.php de la carpeta raíz.